# What are the parts marked VAC1 in this circuit?

Tags: amplifier, integrated-circuit, instrumentation-amplifier

[image]

1. Above is the input state of a 2twochannel EEG. What are the four parts with 5 pins marked VAC1? I couldn't find it at IC search.
2. The ADS1254E 24 bit analog to digital IC is connected to the INA 122U instrumental amplifier, but the 122U only accepts analog input. What amplifier is one supposed to use for the digital output of the ADC? Also can you amplify digital outputs?
3. What kind of resistors are they?

I haven't used a multimeter and oscilloscope yet to probe them because I'm still preparing for antistatic protection like wrist bands before I even touch them. The datasheet of the ADS1254E mentioned it is very ESD sensitive.

Answer (score 3):

1. The parts marked VACI are [TLV2211IDBV](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tlv2211.pdf) op-amps.
2. The ADS1254 is an ADC with serial digital output. It would most likely be connected directly (or possibly through isolators) to a microcontroller.
3. They look like precision resistors.

Comment: It doesn't make sense for the ADC output to get into the INA 122U instrumental amplifier input? What do you make of the INA 122U then? The module has USB isolator. Do you think the USB isolator can protect the ESD sensitive ADS1254 from electrostatic discharge from the fingers?

Comment: @Samzun Any chance they're using the INA122 as a level shifter of some sort?

Comment: Maybe the INA122 is used as  part of a bias driver or something along those lines. I'm thinking of the DRL (Driven Right Leg). Isolation is more to protect the user.

Comment: In the web site, it is mentioned https://www.ti.com/product/INA122#description  "The INA122 is a precision instrumentation amplifier for accurate, low noise differential signal acquisition. Its two-op-amp design provides excellent performance with very low quiescent current, and is ideal for portable instrumentation and data acquisition systems.". How can it be used as level shifter or bias driver?

Comment: Suggest you research how EEG circuits are typically implemented, using the hints above.